# Соответствие тематике сайта вопросов о регулярных выражениях, необходимых автору не для выполнения программистских задач

Tags: обсуждение, тематика

Пример вопроса:

- [Помогите с регулярными выражениями](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/520217/199934)

Автору вопроса регулярные выражения понадобились для поиска/замены в тексте, по всей видимости, он не собирается их использовать для задач программирования.

Регулярные выражения [не относятся](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/165744) к языкам программирования, что их можно подвести под какой-либо пункт [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), не берусь сказать.

Допустимы ли подобные вопросы?

Comment: но ведь поиск/замена вполне себе входит в задачу программирования. Котлетка.

Comment: @Grundy, в приведённом мной примере поиск/замена — как раз не «задача программирования». Собственно, о том и вопрос, разрешать или нет вопросы, где автор использует регулярные выражения не для задач программирования. Какого-то же устойчивого термина «задача программирования» мне нагуглить не удалось. Спасибо.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Регулярные выражения (пусть и не являются языком программирования), самым непосредственным образом относятся к программированию.

CSS и HTML - тоже не языки программирования, а сколько по ним задают вопросов?

Не считаю вопросы о регулярных выражениях оффтопиком.

Comment: Если что, про HTML и CSS [тоже спрашивал](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2984/199934). Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Закрытию "потому что не по теме" такие вопросы не подлежат. Сам язык выражений формален, основные его реализации разрабатываются в языках программирования. В областях, несмежных с разработкой ПО, регулярные выражения практически не встречаются.

С вопросами по этой теме другая беда: у них обычно **низкое качество**. Регулярно встречаю вопросы вида *"вот правила, напишите мне регулярку, пжлст"*. Если указан движок регулярок и правила изложены достаточно точно — уже повезло.

Так что хотя эти вопросы и по теме, это не означает, что их теперь надо все считать хорошими и не минусовать их (раз закрывать нельзя). Как, впрочем, и плохими: никакой вопрос не заслуживает минусов *только* из-за того, что он про регулярки.